MSK, EMR, MWAA automation with ansible in AWS
I need to automate creation of MWAA environment, EMR cluster and MSK cluster in AWS as a part of custom environment build for the customer use case.
I have ansible tool available for automation however, I don't see any ansible module for these components. So can I only use shell module and do it with aws cli in ansible or is there any alternate way available for automating these services.
I can not deviate to other tools like cloud formation or terraform. Automation approach with ansible is preferred.
